# Vectorized difference of 2d numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization, array-broadcasting

I have two numpy arrays A(500,50) and B(100,50) and I want to compute difference between each row of A with all rows of B e.g dist(i,j) is the difference between ith row of A and jth row of B. I want to have an vectorized implementation of this using broadcasting and having no loop.

Implementation using two loops is given bellow:

```
for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    for j in range(B.shape[0])
        dist[i][j]=A[i]-B[j]
```